# How to show an ideal is prime in $F_p[x_1,...,x_4]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, computational-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime number and $$I:=(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_1 x_2+x_1 x_3+x_1 x_4+x_2 x_3+x_2 x_4+x_3 x_4,x_1 x_2 x_3+x_1 x_2 x_4+x_1 x_3 x_4+x_2 x_3 x_4+x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4)$$
be an ideal of $F_p[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$. Is this true $I$ is a prime ideal for any $p$?

I know this is a prime ideal of ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$. I use the Macaulay2 to test the small prime number (say, the prime number less than 100), they are all prime ideal. But how can we show this is prime for any $p$?

Comment: Not sure if this is easier/doable, but if you can show that the variety cut out by this is smooth and connected, it will be prime. Computing the Jacobian might also give that this is generically smooth and connected, which could give finitely many cases to check.

Comment: You'll have to test more primes than that because these "initial coincidences" occur often in prime theory.

Comment: Is there a reason you are interested in this particular ideal?

Comment: @KentaS Yes, this equation over $\mathbb{Q}$  actually defines a special shimura variety which I interseted. I hope this equation still gives an integral shimura variety, which requires this scheme is integral.

Comment: Apparently, it’s always prime for $p<10 000$.

Comment: A Jacobian computation shows that we have smoothness at every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, except those where, in the quotient field, any of the following holds: the four $x_i$ are equal, three of the $x_i$ are zero, or there is a nonzero value $u$ such that two of the $x_i$ are $u$ and the other two are $-u$. I’m not sure how we can show from this that the ideal is prime, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to show that, in $k[a,b,c,d]$ (for any field $k$), the ideal $I$ generated by $\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3+\sigma_4$ is prime (where $\sigma_i$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $i$).

Note that $I$ is generated by $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)-1$ and by $(d+1)(a+b+c+1)+ab+bc+ca-1$.

So $k[a,b,c,d]/I$ is isomorphic to $(k[a,b,c]/(P))[d]/((1+d)(1+c)(1+b)(1+a)-1),$ where $$P=a+b+c+1+(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(ab+bc+ca-1).$$

Thus, we only need to prove that $P \in k[a,b,c]$ is irreducible.

Note that $P$ has degree $2$ with respect to $a$ and is symmetric. Moreover, the leading and constant coefficients of $P$ (wrt $a$) are $(1+b)(1+c)(b+c)$ and $(1+b)(1+c)(bc-1)+b+c+1=bc(b+c+bc)$, so they are coprime in $k[b,c]$.

Thus, if $P$ is reducible, then we can write $P=QR$, where $Q$ and $R$ have degree one with respect to $a$ and are irreducible. The same reasoning shows that $Q,R$ must have degree one with respect to $b$ and $c$ as well.

Since $P$ has total degree $5$, $Q$ and $R$ cannot have the same total degree. Since permuting $a,b,c$ leaves $P$ invariant, it must preserve (up to scalar) the decomposition in irreducibles. Since this action also preserves the total degree, $Q$ and $R$ are $S_3$-invariant (up to scalar).

Since $S_3^{ab}=\{\pm 1\}$, $Q$ and $R$ are at least cyclic. One of them has degree at most two, so it is symmetric, hence $Q,R$ are both symmetric.

If $Q$ has total degree one, then $R$ has total degree four, but degree one with respect to every variable, so it is impossible.

Thus $Q$ has total degree two, so it is of the form $Q(a,b,c)=(ab+bc+ca)+v(a+b+c)+w$ with $v,w \in k$ (up to scalar).

The leading coefficient of $Q$ wrt $a$ must divide $(1+b)(1+c)(b+c)$, and it is $(b+c+v)$: hence $v=0$.

The constant coefficient of $Q$ wrt $a$ must divide $bc(b+c+bc)$, but it is $bc+w$: hence $w=0$.

Therefore $ab+bc+ca \mid P$. This implies $ab+bc+ca \mid abc$, which is clearly impossible, and we are done.

Comment: I am not sure why " we only need to prove that P is irreducible". Let $A:=k[a,b,c]/(P)$, if this is an integral, then how can we show $A[d]/((1+d)(1+c)(1+b)(1+a)−1)$ is also an integral ring? Note that here the polynomial $(1+d)(1+c)(1+b)(1+a)−1$ is irreducible doesn't imply it is a prime ideal since $A[d]$ may not be a UFD.

Comment: $A[d]/((1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)-1)$ is $A[z^{-1}]$, where $z=(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$. It $A$ is a domain, then so is $A[z^{-1}]$.

Comment: If* $A$ is a domain

Comment: sorry, I need more time to check the answer, but the bounty expired, so I use some tricks to make you get the bounty. I am still checking